# Change text of label in parent page by clicking button inside child page within a radtabstrip

Tags: asp.net, events, tabs, rad

My application contains a page "PageA.aspx" with a radtabstrip. One of the tab is associated with a radpageview whose contenturl is "PageB.aspx" which means if I select that particular tab, I will see content of PageB underneath the tab. There is a label in pageA and a button in pageB. I want to change the text of label in PageA  when i press button inside page B. Can anyone tell whether this is possible or not? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

ya...It is Possible in javascript...use Window.parent Property...you can get that label object from that you can change label text...